# Spring not finding Repository annotated class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring application with a domain and persistence layer. In my persistence layer I have DAO's in the form:

```
    public interface PersonDAO {
       public void addPerson(Person person);
       public void updatePerson(Person person);
       public List<Person> listPersons();
       public Person getPersonById(int id);
    }
```

And the Implementation:

```
    @Repository
    public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {
        @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
        private EntityManagerFactory ENITY_MANAGER_FACTORY;

        public PersonDAOImpl(){}

        @Override
        public void addPerson(Person person) {
            EntityManager entityManager = ENITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
           ...
        }
        ...
   }
```

And my spring Java Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("xx.xx.xxxxx.persistence")
public class PersistenceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                               JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter,
                                                                               LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {

      ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter() {
        ...
    }
    ...
   }
```

All the beans in the config load correctly, however, the PersonDAOImpl bean does not load at all when I call it in my main:

```
public class ManagePersons {
    private static EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PersistenceConfig.class);

        ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = ctx.getBean("entityManagerFactory", EntityManagerFactory.class);

        PersonDAO personDAO = ctx.getBean(PersonDAO.class);
      ...
 }
}
```

It throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [xx.xx.xxxxx.persistence.PersonDAO] is defined
```

Comment: what about your componentScan?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Thank You! It works if I also add the ComponentScan annotation. But why would 1 work and not the other?

Comment: Maybe this would have worked for you @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.xxxxx.persistence")

Answer (score 1):

`PersonDAO` should extends a subinterface of `JpaRepository` to be scaned as a jpa repository with `@EnableJpaRepositories`

```
public interface PersonDAO extends Repository<Person, Integer> {
    public void addPerson(Person person);
    public void updatePerson(Person person);
    public List<Person> listPersons();
    public Person getPersonById(Integer id);
}
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.6.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying the following:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.xxxxx.persistence")
```

instead of

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("xx.xx.xxxxx.persistence")
```